# Which executes first, JavaScript in a link or an onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor element `<a>` and an image inside it. Both of them have JavaScript methods.

```
<a href="javascript:someMethod()"><img src="" onclick="someOtherMethod()"></a>
```

Which Javascript function will be executed first, the function in the image `onclick` or the function in the link `href`?

Comment: You can try it and find out.

Comment: You do NOT want to do this. The img first then the href. But it is extremely poor practice to have href="javascript:...

Comment: Inline js is bad. https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS535US535&oq=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.2628j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function inside the `onclick` attribute of the image will execute first.

You can observe this happening in this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mzhmg/).

Comment: really thaaaaaaaaanks :)

And the website is just an amazing :D